# REGEXP like Smarty, but not exactly

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to create something like smarty, but I don't want to use Smarty because I need more functionality with JS...

I want to parse this:

```
{{crossLoopStart fromController->messages as message and increment|i every loop}}
wow, this is message number {{message->id}} and text is: {{message->text}}
{{crossLoopEmpty}}
oh no! You haven't any message!
{{crossLoopEnd}}
```

I made this REGEXP:

```
/\{\{crossLoopStart\s([a-zA-Z0-9>-]+)\s(as\s([a-zA-Z>-]+))?\s?and\s(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\|)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s([a-z]+)\sloop)?\}\}(.+)/
```

But the problem is that when I use `(.+)` (at the end of my REGEXP) it gets all characters:

```
wow, this is message number {{message->id}} and text is: {{message->text}}
{{crossLoopEmpty}}
oh no! You haven't any message!
{{crossLoopEnd}}
```

But I want to get only this:

```
wow, this is message number {{message->id}} and text is: {{message->text}}
```

Not a mandatory part is:

```
{{crossLoopEmpty}}
oh no! You haven't any message!
```

I need to take all the text, ending close of tag symbol "crossLoopStart" **}}** and ending with the opening tag character "crossLoopEmpty" or "crossLoopEnd" **{{**.

Comment: Why don't you just one of the myriad JS templating languages such as Mustache.js see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend

Comment: Why are you adding another templating engine on top of PHP (which is itself a templating engine)?

Comment: Because I need more functionality. I didn't saw same as I want to create. Smart ClientServer Tecnology (templates same on server and client, configs, smart ajax refreshing of elements, etc :)

Comment: NullUserException, This is not simple loop. There will be much more native php,js code, caching system, etc.

Comment: I don't think you understood me. PHP itself is a templating, so you don't need to add another one on top of it. Have your "templates" be straight up PHP code and presto, you can do whatever you want with them. No need to worry about parsing and substituting place holders.

Comment: Ignoring the merits of whatever it is you're doing, for that particular regex, I would extend it to include the optional `{{crossLoopEmpty}}...` bit and look at "lazy quantification" `.+?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what things you're interested in but the following pattern might give you the desired parts.

`/\{\{crossLoopStart\s([a-zA-Z0-9>-]+)\s(as\s([a-zA-Z>-]+))?\s?and\s(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\|)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s([a-z]+)\sloop)?\}\}(.*?)\{\{crossLoopEmpty\}\}(.*?)\{\{crossLoopEnd\}\}/`

With a preg_match you get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{crossLoopStart fromController->messages as message and increment|i every loop}} wow, this is message number {{message->id}} and text is: {{message->text}} {{crossLoopEmpty}} oh no! You haven't any message! {{crossLoopEnd}}
    [1] => fromController->messages
    [2] => as message
    [3] => message
    [4] => increment|i every loop
    [5] => increment|
    [6] => i
    [7] => every
    [8] =>  wow, this is message number {{message->id}} and text is: {{message->text}} 
    [9] =>  oh no! You haven't any message! 
)
```

Comment: +1, that'll get him his template broken up like he wants.  One thing I would add is you can use ^ and $ to limit the match to single lines.  But the approach above makes more sense if you're trying to understand the template as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

{{crossLoopStart\s([a-zA-Z0-9>-]+)\s(as\s([a-zA-Z>-]+))?\s?and\s(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\|)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s([a-z]+)\sloop)?}}[a-z\,\s]{1,}(.*?)\sand[a-z\s]{1,}\:(.*?)\s{{crossLoopEmpty}}\s(.*?)\s{{crossLoopEnd}}

use preg_match( regexp, $string, $match);

Answer (score 0):

What if some parameter will be omitted? How do you control your matches? I think that here you need to use named capturing groups.

```
$r = '/(?P<params>(?<={{crossLoopStart)[^\n]*(?=}}$))}}(?P<content>.+(?={{crossLoopEnd}})){{crossLoopEnd}}/ms';
$m = preg_match($r, $t, $matches);
$params = $matches['params'];
$content = $matches['content'];
$empty_content = '';

if (preg_match('/(?P<content>.*){{crossLoopEmpty}}(?P<emptyContent>.*)/ms', $content, $matches)) {
    $content = $matches['content'];
    $empty_content = $matches['emptyContent'];
}
var_dump($params, $content, $empty_content);
```

In this way you'll know where located your params, content, etc.

```
string(63) " fromController->messages as message and increment|i every loop"
string(76) "
wow, this is message number {{message->id}} and text is: {{message->text}}
"
string(33) "
oh no! You haven't any message!
"
```

And then parse your params in similar way.